# The form of a normal operator with only one element in its spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let be $H$ a Hilbert space. Show that if $T$ is a normal linear operator continuous (i.e. $T^*T = TT^*$, with $T^*$ the Hilbert adjunct of $T$) and your spectrum $\sigma(T) = \{\lambda\}$, than $T = \lambda I$, when $I : H \to H$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T - \lambda I$ is also normal, we have
$$
\| T - \lambda I \| = \text{spr} (T - \lambda I) = 0,
$$
showing that $T = \lambda I$.

(I recently asked basically the same question ([Self-adjoint operator with single point spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742173/self-adjoint-operator-with-single-point-spectrum)), but your formulation is more general so I thought it might be worth sharing the answer here.)

Answer (score 2):

using spectral theorem since $T$ is normal it exist a spectral measure $E$ such that 
$$
Tx=\int_{\sigma(T)}tdE(x)=\int_{\{\lambda\}}tdE(x)=\lambda E(\{\lambda\})(x)=\lambda E(\sigma(T))(x)=\lambda I (x)=\lambda x
$$